# Array data from ui-router state resolve not accessible from within controller after injection

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs, angular-ui-router

This seems so simple yet I have been banging my head against it for hours now...

I have an angular 1.2.29 module that uses ui-router to resolve a data dependency from a service and inject it into a named nested view controller. The service returns my data object exactly as desired and I can inject that returned data into my view controller and log it again with no issue.

What I am baffled by is that if I inspect the object in the console, I can see the array I am trying to access on one of the nested properties of the object I injected from the service (this is from within the context of the controller I am trying to use it in).

However, if I try and pass that array of data into another method in the same controller (in this case a d3 method to draw a graph) - I get nothing but a empty string where the array is.

I can access every other property on the object I passed into the method just fine, and so long as I don't try and access the array directly it is 'visible' to me in my logging, but when I try and pass the array directly in I get an empty string.

I have tried everything I can from making a deep copy or pushing the array into a new object and accessing it that way, trying to cast that property as an array (again into a new object), and a whole host of other random hacks I have run across all to no avail.

I feel like I am missing something incredibly trivial here...

These three logs are called on the same object from within the same method one after the other and you can see the issue.

I am trying to pass the data.datasources.tabledata.datum array to another method that expects an array, but all I can get is the empty string.

Note: 'data' is the object returned from the service resolve at the state transition and injected into the view controller.

```
> console.log(data);

// Expected object.
> Object {datasources: Object}
  datasources: Object
    tabledata: Object
      datum: Array[9383]
      source: "./data/BSGAM_Heads_Wells_Drains_Zones_Master.csv"
      __proto__: Object
    __proto__: Object
  __proto__: Object


> console.log(data.datasources);

// Expected object.
> Object {tabledata: Object}
   tabledata: Object
      datum: Array[9383]
      source: "./data/BSGAM_Heads_Wells_Drains_Zones_Master.csv"
      __proto__: Object
    __proto__: Object

> console.log(data.datasources.tabledata);

// String instead of array... WTH???
> Object {source: "./data/BSGAM_Heads_Wells_Drains_Zones_Master.csv", datum: ""}

> console.log(data.datasources.tabledata.datum);

// Returns NOTHING - not even undefined... just an empty log line @_@
>
```

UPDATE: Here is the service loading the data (it is my own)

```
(function() {
  'use strict';

  angular
    .module('mcsdss.providers')
    .factory('FormulationRetrieval', FormulationRetrieval);

  FormulationRetrieval.$inject = ['$http'];

  function FormulationRetrieval($http) {

    FormulationRetrieval.getFormulation = function (target) {
      var promise = $http
        .get(target)
        .then(function (response) {
          return FormulationRetrieval.configureFormulation(response.data);
        });
      return promise;
    };

    FormulationRetrieval.configureFormulation = function (f) {
      FormulationRetrieval.formulationContainer = f;
      FormulationRetrieval.loadFormulationSourceData(FormulationRetrieval.formulationContainer);
      FormulationRetrieval.loadFormulationGisData(FormulationRetrieval.formulationContainer);
      return FormulationRetrieval.formulationContainer;
    };

    FormulationRetrieval.loadFormulationSourceData = function (fc) {
      function parseFormulationDatasource(fd, destination) {
        Papa.parse(fd, {
          complete: function(results) {
            destination.datum = results.data;
          }
        });
      }

      function loadData(target) {
        var promise = $http
          .get(target.source)
          .then(function (response) {
            parseFormulationDatasource(response.data, target);
          });
        return promise;
      }

      var datasources = [fc.datagridConfig.datasources.tabledata, fc.graphConfig.datasources.graphContextData];
      angular.forEach(datasources, loadData);
    };

    FormulationRetrieval.loadFormulationGisData = function (fc) {
      function loadGeodata(target) {
        angular.forEach(target, function(value, key) {
          var promise = $http
            .get(value.source)
            .then(function (response) {
              value.datum = response.data;
            });
          return promise;
        });
      }

      var datasources = [fc.mapConfig.datasources.geojson];
      angular.forEach(datasources, loadGeodata);
    };

    FormulationRetrieval.getAnalysisConfig = function (fc) {
      var analysisConfig = fc.analysisConfig;
      return analysisConfig;
    };

    FormulationRetrieval.getMaufConfig = function (fc) {
      var maufConfig = fc.maufConfig;
      return maufConfig;
    };

    FormulationRetrieval.getGraphConfig = function (fc) {
      var graphConfig = fc.graphConfig;
      return graphConfig;
    };

    FormulationRetrieval.getTableConfig = function (fc) {
      var tableConfig = fc.datagridConfig;
      return tableConfig;
    };

    FormulationRetrieval.getMapConfig = function (fc) {
      var mapConfig = fc.mapConfig;
      return mapConfig;
    };

    return FormulationRetrieval;
  }
})();
```

Here is the ui-router resolve on the state:

```
(function() {
  'use strict';

  angular
    .module('analyze')
    .config(DashboardRoutes);

  DashboardRoutes.$inject = ['$stateProvider'];

  function DashboardRoutes($stateProvider) {

    // Define states.
    var analyze_state = {
      abstract: true,
      url: '/analyze',
      templateUrl: 'modules/analyze/views/analyze.client.view.html',
      controller: 'AnalyzeViewController',
      controllerAs: 'analyze',
      data: {
        title: 'Analyze'
      },
      resolve: {
        analysisData: function(FormulationRetrieval) {
          return FormulationRetrieval.getFormulation('./data/formulations/bs.formulation.json');
        },
        analysisConfig: function(FormulationRetrieval, analysisData) {
          return FormulationRetrieval.getAnalysisConfig(analysisData);
        },
        maufConfig: function(FormulationRetrieval, analysisData) {
          return FormulationRetrieval.getMaufConfig(analysisData);
        },
        tableConfig: function(FormulationRetrieval, analysisData) {
          return FormulationRetrieval.getTableConfig(analysisData);
        },
        graphConfig: function(FormulationRetrieval, analysisData) {
          return FormulationRetrieval.getGraphConfig(analysisData);
        },
        mapConfig: function(FormulationRetrieval, analysisData) {
          return FormulationRetrieval.getMapConfig(analysisData);
        }
      }
    };

    var analyze_layout_state = {
      abstract: false,
      url: '',
      views: {
        'graph': {
          templateUrl: 'modules/analyze/views/analyze.graph.client.view.html',
          controller: 'GraphViewController'
        },
        'map': {
          templateUrl: 'modules/analyze/views/analyze.map.client.view.html',
          controller: 'MapViewController'
        },
        'filters': {
          templateUrl: 'modules/analyze/views/analyze.filters.client.view.html',
          controller: 'FiltersViewController',
          controllerAs: 'filters'
        },
        'datatable': {
          templateUrl: 'modules/analyze/views/analyze.datatable.client.view.html',
          controller: 'DatatableViewController',
          controllerAs: 'datatable'
        }
      }
    };

    // Populate provider.
    $stateProvider
      .state('analyze', analyze_state)
      .state('analyze.layout', analyze_layout_state);
  }
})();
```

And here is the controller receiving the injected data:

```
(function() {
  'use strict';

  angular
    .module('analyze')
    .controller('AnalyzeViewController', AnalyzeViewController);

  AnalyzeViewController.$inject = ['$rootScope', '$scope', '$state', '$location', 'Authentication', 'httpq', 'analysisData', 'maufConfig', 'tableConfig', 'graphConfig', 'mapConfig'];

  function AnalyzeViewController($rootScope, $scope, $state, $location, Authentication, $httpq, analysisData, analysisConfig, maufConfig, tableConfig, graphConfig, mapConfig) {
    // This provides Authentication context.
    $scope.authentication = Authentication;
    $scope.currentRoute = 'Analyze';
    // console.log($scope.currentRoute);

    // ALL OF THESE ARE INJECTED AND APPEAR TO BE CORRECT IN CONSOLE.
    // console.log(analysisData);
    // console.log(analysisConfig);
    // console.log(maufConfig);
    // console.log(tableConfig);
    // console.log(graphConfig);
    // console.log(mapConfig);

// NOTE: At one point I was loading the data through promises inside the
//controller, but moved it into the state resolve for better SOC. 
//Strangely the $broadcast of the exact same value done here in the finally()
//block of the $httpq method works - using the new injected data object! 
//And yet, the same $broadcast on $stateChangeSuccess (which DOES send the correct
//data into the listening subscribers if I only send the entire object) sends only
//empty string if I specify the array.

    // Manual data loading.
    $scope.sourceFile_A = './data/BSGAM_Heads_Wells_Drains_Zones_Master.csv';

    $httpq.get($scope.sourceFile_A)
      .then(function(data) {
        // ...removed because not used.
      })
      .catch(function(data, status) {
        console.error('Load error', response.status, response.data);
      })
      .finally(function() {
        // Works here using the injected resolved promise, does not work in stateChangeSuccess... WTH??
        $scope.$broadcast('analysisDataLoaded', analysisData.datagridConfig.datasources.tabledata.datum);
      });

    $scope.$on('$stateChangeSuccess', function() {
      // EXACT SAME BROADCAST AS ABOVE FAILS HERE - EMPTY STRING.
      // $scope.$broadcast('analysisDataLoaded', analysisData.datagridConfig.datasources.tabledata.datum);
    });

    // extra code removed...

})();
```

Lastly the Nested View Controller (one of 4) that I am trying to get to use the data via the $broadcast from the abstract parent. I can also access all the injected objects here directly without the broadcast but I am trying to decouple as much as possible as several views need to update in sync from the broadcast.

```
(function() {
  'use strict';

  angular
    .module('analyze')
    .controller('DatatableViewController', DatatableViewController);

  DatatableViewController.$inject = ['$scope', 'Authentication', '$filter', 'ngTableParams', 'AnalysisDataFactory', 'tableConfig'];

  function DatatableViewController($scope, Authentication, $filter, ngTableParams, AnalysisDataFactory, tableConfig) {
    // This provides Authentication context.
    $scope.authentication = Authentication;

    // Expose public API.
    $scope.headerFilter = headerFilter;
    $scope.datasetOrder = datasetOrder;
    $scope.rowClicked = rowClicked;
    $scope.decorateSiblings = decorateSiblings;
    $scope.clearSiblings = clearSiblings;
    $scope.updateView = updateView;

    // Private members.
    $scope.headerdata = [];
    $scope.tabledata = [];
    $scope.suf01 = 0;
    $scope.suf02 = 0;
    $scope.suf03 = 0;
    $scope.muf = 0;

    $scope.$on('analysisDataLoaded', function(event, args) {
      console.log('analysisDataLoaded...', event, args);
      $scope.updateView(args);
       // THIS IS WHAT I WANT TO DO INSTEAD:
      // $scope.updateView(tableConfig);    // Not working yet.
    });

    function headerFilter(target) {
      return target.visible;
    }

    function datasetOrder(key) {    
      angular.forEach($scope.headers, function(target) {
        // console.log('key='+key);
        if (target.data == key) {
          if (target.visible) {
            return target.order;
          }
        }
      });
      return -1;
    }

    function rowClicked(target) {   
      for (var key in target) {
        if (target.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
          console.log(key + ' -> ' + target[key]);
        }
      }
    }

    function decorateSiblings(target) {
      // console.log('data row touched, sending emission.');
      $scope.$emit('currentDatatableTarget', target);
    }

    function clearSiblings(target) {
      // console.log('datarow cleared, sending all clear.');
      $scope.$emit('clearDatatableTarget', target);
    }

    function updateView(data) {    
      // ngTable    
      $scope.dataTable = new ngTableParams({
        page: 1,
        count: 10
      }, {
        total: $scope.tabledata.length,
        counts: [10, 25, 50, 100, 250],
        defaultSort: 'asc',
        getData: function($defer, params) {
          $scope.data = params.sorting() ? $filter('orderBy')($scope.tabledata, params.orderBy()) : $scope.tabledata;
          $scope.data = params.filter() ? $filter('filter')(data, params.filter()) : data;
          $scope.data = data.slice((params.page() - 1) * params.count(), params.page() * params.count());
          $defer.resolve($scope.data);
        }
      });    
    }
  }
})();
```

Something simple in here - probably a JS gotcha that I am overlooking.... Thanks in advance for any input!!

Comment: In case it helps, this is a multi-dimensional array of nested arrays...

Comment: Is it a 3rd party service you're using, or is it your own service? Can you show the relevant code for the service?

Comment: My own service - I will update the code.

Comment: OK, thats all the context I can think of... really baffled here. 

Especially by the same $broadcast working in the mostly abandoned $httpq method but not the subsequent $stateChangeSuccess method in the AnalyzeViewController.

Comment: `console.log` can be a bit confusing when logging objects that get updated at a later time in that you will only see the latest value and not necessarily what it looked like at the time of logging. What's likely happening is that you are trying to access a property **before** an asynchronous operation completes and populates said property with data

Comment: I thought the point of the state resolve was to ensure the data was all loaded into the injected object the controller is receiving before transitioning into the new state? 

If I screw up the data, the state wont load and the app wont transition to the analysis view - which is expected. And I can still access and log all the data properties from the injected objects from within any of the resolved views at any time, I just cant seem to get the array data to pass properly.

Comment: Literally, one line after the next within the same context, log same object, array on one - string on the other (if the specific property where the array is at is specified in the log).

Which is the initial conditions I posted at the top...

Comment: I'd try to narrow down the problem a bit. There is far too much code for anyone to look at - makes it especially hard for obscure problems. Try to remove dependencies, eliminate lines of code that you know don't contribute to the problem, until you have something more manageable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out it was from not properly deferring and resolving the promises before trying to bind to them. I still have not identified exactly where that timing is going wrong in my code, but I can now intermittently load the data as I intended and can see that it is clearly a function of async inconsistencies. The $broadcast event is working just fine (when the async data loads properly).